# checked state in Sencha Touch

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, extjs

I can get checkbox state with:

```
var c = Ext.getCmp("my_checkbox").checked;
```

but I can get checkbox changes ?

is there something i need to code in to make visual changes?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question entirely. Do you want to be able to do/change something on the page when the checkbox is checked/unchecked?

Comment: Some checkboxes are going to be checked, some unchecked
and user can change state.

When he's done, i need to collect all the checkboxes with changed state, but currently I don't get changed state

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this in Sencha Touch, you will need to add event listeners to the Ext.form.Checkbox component. You can do this using the following code:

```
new Ext.form.Checkbox({
    id: 'my_checkbox',
    listeners: {
        check: function() {
            alert('I was checked!');
        },
        uncheck: function() {
            alert('I was unchecked!');
        }
    }
});
```

In the future, it is best to post your questions on the [Sencha Forums](http://www.sencha.com/forum/), as you will get a faster response there.

**Update**
Updated answer for your comment:

```
var filter = {
    id: 'filter',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            items: [
                {
                    type: 'checkboxfield',
                    name: 'city[1]',
                    label: 'city',
                    id: 'city1',
                    checked: true,
                    listeners: {
                        check: function() {
                            //do something
                        },
                        uncheck: function() {
                            //do something
                        }
                    }
                }
            ] // END items
        }
    ] // END items
};
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll use Sencha forum in the future. Regarding your answer: do I need to follow every checkbox click, or is there way to get only the final state by pressing the button ?

Comment: just one more thing,
in what do i change :

new Ext.form.Checkbox({    
 id: 'my_checkbox'  

if i have this structure:

        var filter = {
            id: 'filter',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'fieldset',
                items: [{
                    type: 'checkboxfield',
                    name: 'city[1]',
                    label: 'city',
                    id: 'city1',
                    checked: true,
                }
                ] // END items 
            }] // END items
        };

Comment: I updated my answer to accommodate your situation. And yes, you need to follow each event and respond appropriately.

Comment: hey rdougan great answer,I am facing some problem to get state of checkbox added in list in sencha touch 2.0.So can you help me.http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?197969-How-to-get-the-checkbox-state-added-in-itemTpl&p=788962#post788962 this is the question i have posted.Thanx in advance.